# No power delivery with PoE though a tested cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, cabling, power-over-ethernet

I'm facing an issue with PoE and a cable extension.

I have an HP 1920-48-PoE+ (JG928A) switch and a Cat6 wire installation. All the house wiring is connected directly to the PoE switch. I want to install a PoE-enabled camera on the terrace, but since it was not initially wired, I had to install a new cable section, from a wall socket to the terrace, through a corrugated tube (I know, it's super dirty, but I've got no choice).

This new section is a [Cat7 S/FTP copper solid](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07ZVKY44T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1), and it's connected to the closest ethernet socket. The extension may have 20m and the wire from the switch to the socket may have another 30m max. So it's pretty far away from the 100m limit.

I have checked that the cable is properly crimped, both ends with [TIA-568B](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA-568B). The tester lights are strong and steady for all 8 wires on both ends. I have network connection through the cable, tested with my laptop.

I also checked that the wire, if connected directly to the wall socket, properly powers the camera.

I think that petty much describes my situation.

My next step was to create a new wire from my Cat7 spool and check if it works.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: So you're saying the new cable only fails when it's in the tube?

Comment: Are your 8P8C male connectors rated for solid Cat7 cable? Most crimp-on male 8P8C connectors can only handle stranded cable, and the thinner conductors (higher AWG number) of the older UTP types. What is the AWG of your cable?